Create Contacts API payload is not working as expected
I'm having a problem with Create Contacts api payload, i'm sending this specific payload witch can be found in the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_contacts/createContacts.html
I'm getting this error below:
400Bad Request
{
    "operationStatus": "FAIL",
    "rowsAffected": 0,
    "requestServiceMessageID": "870cb9ae-f485-4c99-b36d-fe0248cd66c4",
    "responseDateTime": "2024-06-20T07:27:37.6036439-06:00",
    "hasErrors": true,
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "formatStringParams": [
                "ValueDefinition",
                null,
                null,
                "CreatedDate"
            ],
            "messageFormatString": "Unable to resolve schema element of type: {0} by reference. [Id: {1}, Key: {2}, Name: {3}]",
            "resultType": "Validation",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "SchemaObjectNotFoundByReference",
            "message": "Unable to resolve schema element of type: ValueDefinition by reference. [Id: , Key: , Name: CreatedDate]"
        },
        {
            "formatStringParams": [
                "ValueDefinition",
                null,
                null,
                "ModifiedDate"
            ],
            "messageFormatString": "Unable to resolve schema element of type: {0} by reference. [Id: {1}, Key: {2}, Name: {3}]",
            "resultType": "Validation",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "SchemaObjectNotFoundByReference",
            "message": "Unable to resolve schema element of type: ValueDefinition by reference. [Id: , Key: , Name: ModifiedDate]"
        }
    ],
    "serviceMessageID": "03a94bfb-9e5e-4eeb-87cb-4ab7ad6f9c48"
}

Has anyone been through this and can help me solve this? I already try contact support.
My goal is to allow optin on whatsapp channel.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Does this answer your question? Creating a new contact using the REST API resulting in 400 bad request
